# Is this a good REST URI?

Tags: c#, wcf, rest, uri

Is the following URI good in REST or how can it be improved?

This is the service definition: (REST and SOAP - WCF)

```
    [OperationContract]
    [WebGet(ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, UriTemplate = "/Services?CostCentreNo={CostCentreNo}&Filter={Filter}")]
    List<Services> GetServices(Int32 CostCentreNo, Int32 Filter);
```

This would give an example URI as:

```
    http://paul-hp:1337/WCF.IService.svc/rest/Services?CostCentreNo=1&Filter=1
```

I have a lot of get methods.
and a few insert methods. Is the URI acceptable. Does it need `GET/` in it or something?

**edit:**
Okay, now i undstand it more:
 So If I had a sub service, it would(could) be

```
    /CostCenters/{CostCentreNo}/Services/{ServiceID}/SubService
```

and, Insert Room booking (with over 20 parameters) could be

```
   /CostCentres/{CostCentreNo}/Rooms/{RoomNo}/Booking?param1={param1}....&param20=‌​{param20}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

hmm... one of the reasons folks use REST is to avoid query strings for anything *other* than actual queries. In your case, a CostCentre probably deserves its own URL, as well as a separate URL for its services. Based on your example, in my opinion only the Filter should be a query string.

I would structure your URL as follows:

> ```
> /CostCenters/{CostCentreNo}/Services?Filter={Filter}
> ```

**Edit:**

> Okay, now i undstand it more: So If I had a sub service, it
>   would(could) be
>
> ```
> /CostCenters/{CostCentreNo}/Services/{ServiceID}/SubService  and,
> ```
>
> Insert Room booking (with over 20 parameters) could be
>
> ```
> /CostCentres/{CostCentreNo}/Rooms/{RoomNo}/Booking?param1={param1}....&param20=‌​{param20}
> ```

I would recommend granting individual entities that can exist on their own URLs that are closer to the parent hierarchy, if possible. Obviously I don't know your system, but my guess is that you might want to do something along the lines of:

> ```
> /CostCenters/{CostCenterNo}
> /Services/{ServiceID}
> /Rooms/{RoomNo}
> ```

Only use hierarchies like

> ```
> /CostCenters/{CostCentreNo}/Services/{ServiceID}/
> ```

when a Service cannot exist without a CostCenter. If that is the case, by all means, go with such a hierarchy. If a Service can exist without a CostCenter, go with the former hierarchy above.

One last thing. This URL from your example:

> ```
> /CostCenters/{CostCentreNo}/Services/{ServiceID}/SubService
> ```

only makes sense if a Service can have one and only one SubService. I'm betting that your example needs a SubServiceID or something similar. And following my advice above, I would definitely say that a SubService absolutely would need to be extending a Service URL, e.g.:

> ```
> /Services/{ServiceID}/SubServices/{SubServiceID}
> ```

In the above case, I would expect that a SubServiceID references the same entity pool as ServiceID, and that whatever data or view is returned by this URL would include both the Service and SubService.

Comment: Actually, that's not really true.  `/location?x=100&y=230` is a perfectly reasonable use of query string parameters that isn't really a query.  Query params are useful for identifying resources that are not naturally hierarchical.

Comment: @DarrelMiller: absolutely true -- when REST doesn't work, you must fall back on query strings. But my point is that REST is about establishing simple URLs for entities in your system wherever possible. Query strings, in a RESTful system, are for searching for those entities.

Comment: @Randolpho Rest says nothing about query strings vs path segments.  Rest is absolutely not about simple urls.

Comment: @DarrelMiller: You're right, I miswrote. REST is about *static* URLs for entities. Included within that is an unwritten implication that it's best that the static URLs be as simple as possible. Regardless, query strings are not static.

Comment: @Randolpho  Can you point me to some documentation/specification that says REST is about static URLs for entities?  Roy even goes as far as to say "A REST API must not define fixed resource names" which to me seems contradictory to what you are saying.  http://roy.gbiv.com/untangled/2008/rest-apis-must-be-hypertext-driven